# How to run the command 'pdflatex' in Java on Mac

Tags: java, macos, terminal, command, pdflatex

I've tried searching for the answer but none are working for me.

I'm trying to run pdflatex in terminal from my java application on my Mac.

In Terminal if i type:

```
open -a FireFox http://www.yahoo.co.uk
```

it opens yahoo.co.uk in my FireFox browser

or

```
pdflatex x.tex
```

it processes the file

In my Java code I type:

```
open -a FireFox http://www.yahoo.co.uk'
```

it opens yahoo.co.uk in my FireFox browser

or

```
pdflatex x.tex
```

I get an error.

Here's the Code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    String s = null;

    try {

        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("pdflatex x.tex");

         BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new
         InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

         BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new
         InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

         // read the output from the command
         System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
         while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
         System.out.println(s);
         }

         // read any errors from the attempted command
         System.out.println("Here is the standard error of the command (if any):\n");
         while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
         System.out.println(s);
         }

         System.exit(0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("exception happened - here's what I know: ");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }
}
```

Here's the error:

> exception happened - here's what I know: 
>   java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "pdflatex": error=2, No such file or directory at 
>   java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:460) at 
>   java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:593) at 
>   java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:431) at 
>   java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:328) at 
>   test.JavaRunCommand.main(JavaRunCommand.java:28) 
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory at  
>   java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method) at 
>   java.lang.UNIXProcess.(UNIXProcess.java:53) at 
>   java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:91) at 
>   java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:453)   ... 4 more

I have tried JProc as it was a solution from another post, but it still has a similar error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.buildobjects.process.StartupException: 
>   Could not startup process 'pdflatex x.tex '. 
>   at org.buildobjects.process.Proc.(Proc.java:46) at 
>   org.buildobjects.process.ProcBuilder.run(ProcBuilder.java:111) at 
>   test.JavaRunCommand.main(JavaRunCommand.java:20)  
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: 
>   Cannot run program "pdflatex x.tex": error=2, No such file or directory at 
>   java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:460) at 
>   java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:593) at  
>   org.buildobjects.process.Proc.(Proc.java:43)    ... 2 more 
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory at 
>   java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method) at 
>   java.lang.UNIXProcess.(UNIXProcess.java:53) at 
>   java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:91) at 
>   java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:453)   ... 4 more

Comment: Try printing `which pdflatex` in command line, then replacing `pdflatex` in the Java code with its full name.

Comment: Thanks @alf! It worked! but now I want to open the pdf file generated. How do I call pdflatex AND open the resulting pdf file in one go?

Comment: I have done it - I wrote a batch file and executed that. Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

thanks to @alf :

printing `which pdflatex` and using the resulting full path works perfectly.